After grouping, is there a way to put the groups back into an array?
I'm using JSONata to transform a flat list of objects into a more complex structure. I used grouping to create the objects the way I want. Problem is it creates a dictionary of objects where the key is the value of the objects. What I want is to put them into an array instead. Can this be done? Will I need to use a function? I tried using $spread but that didn't seem to do what I was wanting.
Here's my JSON:
{
  "JDEOW_EPO": [
    {
            "ItemDescription": "TEST 8.5",
            "BuildProDocument/Document/DocNumber": "11",
            "ExtendedPrice": 10.00
    },
    {
            "ItemDescription": "TEST 8.5",
            "BuildProDocument/Document/DocNumber": "11",
            "ExtendedPrice": 2.00
    },
    {
            "ItemDescription": "TEST 8.5",
            "BuildProDocument/Document/DocNumber": "12",
            "ExtendedPrice": 2.0
    }
  ]
}

Here's my expression:
$$.JDEOW_EPO{`BuildProDocument/Document/DocNumber`: {
    "Description":$[0].ItemDescription,
    "Lines": $[].{
        "Amount":$.ExtendedPrice
    }
}}

Here's the output:
{
  "11": {
    "Description": "TEST 8.5",
    "Lines": [
      {
        "Amount": 10
      },
      {
        "Amount": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  "12": {
    "Description": "TEST 8.5",
    "Lines": [
      {
        "Amount": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}

Here's what I want to transform it into:
[
  {
    "Description": "TEST 8.5",
    "Lines": [
      {
        "Amount": 10
      },
      {
        "Amount": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Description": "TEST 8.5",
    "Lines": [
      {
        "Amount": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]


It turns out I was almost there. Just had to add the $each function to the outside if the expression. It looks like this:
$each($$.JDEOW_EPO{`BuildProDocument/Document/DocNumber`: {
    "Description":$[0].ItemDescription,
    "Lines": $[].{
        "Amount":$.ExtendedPrice
    }
}}, function($v,$k){$v})

This yielded the following:
[
  {
    "Description": "TEST 8.5",
    "Lines": [
      {
        "Amount": 10
      },
      {
        "Amount": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Description": "TEST 8.5",
    "Lines": [
      {
        "Amount": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]

But then I wondered, what if I wanted to encapsulate the array as a key in an outer object. So I added one more predicate like this:
$each($$.JDEOW_EPO{`BuildProDocument/Document/DocNumber`: {
    "Description":$[0].ItemDescription,
    "Lines": $[].{
        "Amount":$.ExtendedPrice
    }
}}, function($v,$k){$v}).${"EPOs":$}

That gave me a final output of:
{
  "EPOs": [
    {
      "Description": "TEST 8.5",
      "Lines": [
        {
          "Amount": 10
        },
        {
          "Amount": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Description": "TEST 8.5",
      "Lines": [
        {
          "Amount": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Hope this helps someone one day.
